# Making certain words bold or italic [VSCode]

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am currently working with classes, and I would like the keyword "self" to stand out by making it bold.

I have searched around the internet and cannot find anything of use. I managed to get comments to turn italic but I can't figure out how to make certain words a specific font style.

Any ideas?

my current settings.json

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
                "scope": "comment",
                "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
        }]
    },
    "json.schemas": [
    ]
    
    
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at the extension HighLight

Comment: I had a look, but it only seems to highlight certain words rather than change the font type

Comment: Highlight can easily change a word to bold and/or italics and much more. From its docs: 

"All the supported decoration options are defined here."   linking to https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions

Comment: Hey @Mark, thanks for the reply. There are many Highlight extensions, so could you give the author that created the one you are on about so I can look into it?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Comment: Ok thanks, and how would I make 'self' bold with this? I don't see any way to do it in the settings or instruction page. I have 0 clue about json, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make specific words bold or italic, you can only style tokens/scopes the way you want.

The simplest way to find the token for the words you want to style is to use the "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" option
[image: inspect]

Then select the word you want to get the scope for

[image: scopes]

Style the active scope as you like in your `settings.json`

Read more : [Syntax Highlighting Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)